# rename column after transpose

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

I have an issue while renaming column. As you see below, I can change column name or index, it does not rename the column name which is what i want to do. Any help please.

The code:

```
 d_price = pd.concat(d_price, axis=1)
 d_price = d_price.transpose()
 print(d_price)
```

The output:

```
          0
1WO  2.5400
ADH  0.2722
ALX  0.5223
```

The code:

```
d_price = pd.concat(d_price, axis=1)
d_price = d_price.transpose()
d_price.index.names = ['jp']
print(d_price)
```

The output:

```
          0
jp         
1WO  2.5400
ADH  0.2722
ALX  0.5223
```

The code:

```
d_price = pd.concat(d_price, axis=1)
d_price = d_price.transpose()
d_price.columns.names = ['jpy_price']
print(d_price)
```

The output:

```
jpy_price       0
1WO        2.5400
ADH        0.2722
ALX        0.5223
```

Comment: If this is related to pandas, add the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of renaming is incorrect. Try this way:

```
df.head()

    0
1WO 2.5400
ADH 0.2722
ALX 0.5223

df.columns = ["jpy_price"]

df.head()

    jpy_price
1WO 2.5400
ADH 0.2722
ALX 0.5223

or

df.rename(columns={"0":"jpy_price"}, inplace=True)
df.head()

    jpy_price
1WO 2.5400
ADH 0.2722
ALX 0.5223
```

Comment: @maf Do watch out for the default column naming by pandas, like in case of groupby followed by reset_index column names comes as 0 (Int type) not str type, like this ```df.rename(columns={0:"jpy_price"}, inplace=True)```

Answer (score 0):

```
d_price.rename(index=str, columns={0: "New name"})
```